# How to validate a text in disabled field [Geb]?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, ui-automation, spock, geb

I have an UI form where I have to first select the username field (ex: product) and if I click on Submit button a popup window which then populates a hidden field with an ID and a display field with the username (product).

The display field is set to disabled="disabled" to force the user to use the popup and not type a value in the field.How could I validate the below using Geb Spoc?

```
<td class="Data" style="white-space:pre">
<input id="amazon" class="FormElement" name="amazon" size="20" role="textbox" disabled="disabled" type="text">
</td>
```

I have tried with the below page objects and Spec test
Page:

```
selectUser {$("#amazon")}
```

Spec:

```
assert selectUser.text() == "product"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the `value()` method because you're accessing the value of an input and not the `text()` method as you are not after the inner text of the input element.

Comment: I have tried with value(), it didn't work. It is returning null value.. Actually the value in the text box was disabled. Please let me know your thoughts on how to verify the disabled value?